# throw exception when Java JNI experiences segmentation fault

Tags: java, java-native-interface, segmentation-fault

We have code running JNI in a separate thread.  We occasionally get segmentation faults while developing that we need to debug, but because the code is running in a separate thread the seg-fault isn't reported.  Instead the thread essentially dies without warning making debugging difficult.

I would like to be able to either detect a segmentation fault and/or throw an exception when a seg fault occurs so that we have some indication that a thread has died without warning.  Is there any way to detect segmentation faults in this manner?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On windows, use [SetUnhandledExceptionFilter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms680634%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) or use a `__try __except` construct to catch exceptions in the thread. On POSIX platforms, install a handler for `SIGSEGV` with `sigaction`

Comment: and then throw them up to the JVM after catching them.
jclass clazz = (*jenv)->FindClass(jenv, "java/lang/IllegalStateException");
    (*jenv)->ThrowNew(jenv, clazz, "Caught seg fault");